# IA32 CPU, protected mode: which data is saved to the stack when an interrupt takes place?

Tags: interrupt, protected-mode, x86

I would like to know the size in bytes that each piece of data uses in the stack. How does the privilege level affect the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:

If the interrupt is in a higher privelege level, SS and ESP are pushed to the stack, each one consuming 4 bytes. For the same level this step is skipped.

Then EFLAGS, CS and EIP are pushed to the stack, each one using 4 bytes too. So you will most likely have 20 bytes on the stack.

There are many complicted execptions and rules for task gates, faults, context switches etc, so long answer in pseudo code from [x86/x64 Instruction Set Reference](http://siyobik.info/main/reference/instruction/INT%20n/INTO/INT%203):

```
(* The following operational description applies not only to the INT n and INTO instructions, but also to external interrupts, nonmaskable interrupts (NMIs), and exceptions. Some of these events push onto the stack an error code. *)
(* The operational description specifies numerous checks whose failure may result in delivery of a nested exception. In these cases, the original event is not delivered. *)
(* The operational description specifies the error code delivered by any nested exception. In some cases, the error code is specified with a pseudofunction error_code(num, idt, ext), where idt and ext are bit values. The pseudofunction produces an error code as follows: *)
(* (1) if idt is 0, the error code is (num & FCH) | ext; *)
(* (2) if idt is 1, the error code is (num << 3) | 2 | ext. *)
(* In many cases, the pseudofunction error_code is invoked with a pseudovariable EXT. The value of EXT depends on the nature of the event whose delivery encountered a nested exception: if that event is a software interrupt, EXT is 0;otherwise, EXT is 1. *)
IF PE = 0
    GOTO REAL-ADDRESS-MODE;
ELSE
    IF PE = 1
        IF (VM = 1 and IOPL < 3 AND INT n)
            #GP(0); (* Bit 0 of error code is 0 because INT n *)
        ELSE
            (* Protected mode, IA-32e mode, or virtual-8086 mode interrupt *)
            IF (IA32_EFER.LMA = 0)
                (* Protected mode, or virtual-8086 mode interrupt *)
                GOTO PROTECTED-MODE;
            ELSE
                (* IA-32e mode interrupt *)
                GOTO IA-32e-MODE;
            FI;
        FI;
    FI;
FI;
REAL-ADDRESS-MODE:
    IF ((vector_number << 2) + 3) is not within IDT limit
        #GP;
    FI;
    IF stack not large enough for a 6-byte return information
        #SS;
    FI;
    Push (EFLAGS[15:0]);
    IF = 0; (* Clear interrupt flag *)
    TF = 0; (* Clear trap flag *)
    AC = 0; (* Clear AC flag *)
    Push(CS);
    Push(IP);
    (* No error codes are pushed in real-address mode *)
    CS = IDT(Descriptor (vector_number << 2), selector));
    EIP = IDT(Descriptor (vector_number << 2), offset)); (* 16 bit offset AND 0000FFFFH *)
END;
PROTECTED-MODE:
    IF ((vector_number << 3) + 7) is not within IDT limits or selected IDT descriptor is not an interrupt-, trap-, or task-gate type
        #GP(error_code(vector_number, 1, EXT));
    FI;
    (* idt operand to error_code set because vector is used *)
    IF software interrupt (* Generated by INT n, INT3, or INTO *)
        IF gate DPL < CPL (* PE = 1, DPL < CPL, software interrupt *)
            #GP(error_code(vector_number, 1, 0));
        FI;
        (* idt operand to error_code set because vector is used *)
        (* ext operand to error_code is 0 because INT n, INT3, or INTO *)
    FI;
    IF gate not present
        #NP(error_code(vector_number, 1, EXT));
    FI;
    (* idt operand to error_code set because vector is used *)
    IF task gate (* Specified in the selected interrupt table descriptor *)
        GOTO TASK-GATE;
    ELSE
        GOTO TRAP-OR-INTERRUPT-GATE; (* PE = 1, trap/interrupt gate *)
    FI;
END;
IA-32e-MODE:
    IF INTO and CS.L = 1 (64-bit mode)
        #UD;
    FI;
    IF ((vector_number << 4) + 15) is not in IDT limits or selected IDT descriptor is not an interrupt-, or trap-gate type
        #GP(error_code(vector_number, 1, EXT));
        (* idt operand to error_code set because vector is used *)
    FI;
    IF software interrupt (* Generated by INT n, INT 3, or INTO *)
        IF gate DPL < CPL (* PE = 1, DPL < CPL, software interrupt *)
            #GP(error_code(vector_number, 1, 0)); (* idt operand to error_code set because vector is used *)
            (* ext operand to error_code is 0 because INT n, INT3, or INTO *)
        FI;
    FI;
    IF gate not present
        #NP(error_code(vector_number, 1, EXT));
        (* idt operand to error_code set because vector is used *)
    FI;
    GOTO TRAP-OR-INTERRUPT-GATE; (* Trap/interrupt gate *)
END;
TASK-GATE: (* PE = 1, task gate *)
    Read TSS selector in task gate (IDT descriptor);
    IF local/global bit is set to local or index not within GDT limits
        #GP(error_code(TSS selector, 0, EXT));
    FI; (* idt operand to error_code is 0 because selector is used *)
    Access TSS descriptor in GDT;
    IF TSS descriptor specifies that the TSS is busy (low-order 5 bits set to 00001)
        #GP(TSS selector, 0, EXT));
    FI; (* idt operand to error_code is 0 because selector is used *)
    IF TSS not present
        #NP(TSS selector, 0, EXT));
    FI; (* idt operand to error_code is 0 because selector is used *)
    SWITCH-TASKS (with nesting) to TSS;
    IF interrupt caused by fault with error code
        IF stack limit does not allow push of error code
            #SS(EXT);
        FI;
        Push(error code);
    FI;
    IF EIP not within code segment limit
        #GP(EXT);
    FI;
END;
TRAP-OR-INTERRUPT-GATE:
    Read new code-segment selector for trap or interrupt gate (IDT descriptor);
    IF new code-segment selector is NULL
        #GP(EXT);
    FI; (* Error code contains NULL selector *)
    IF new code-segment selector is not within its descriptor table limits
        #GP(error_code(new code-segment selector, 0, EXT));
    FI;
    (* idt operand to error_code is 0 because selector is used *)
    Read descriptor referenced by new code-segment selector;
    IF descriptor does not indicate a code segment or new code-segment DPL > CPL
        #GP(error_code(new code-segment selector, 0, EXT));
    FI;
    (* idt operand to error_code is 0 because selector is used *)
    IF new code-segment descriptor is not present,
        #NP(error_code(new code-segment selector, 0, EXT));
    FI;
    (* idt operand to error_code is 0 because selector is used *)
    IF new code segment is non-conforming with DPL < CPL
        IF VM = 0
            GOTO INTER-PRIVILEGE-LEVEL-INTERRUPT; (* PE = 1, VM = 0, interrupt or trap gate, nonconforming code segment, DPL < CPL *)
        ELSE
            (* VM = 1 *)
            IF new code-segment DPL != 0
                #GP(error_code(new code-segment selector, 0, EXT)); (* idt operand to error_code is 0 because selector is used *)
                GOTO INTERRUPT-FROM-VIRTUAL-8086-MODE;
            FI;
            (* PE = 1, interrupt or trap gate, DPL < CPL, VM = 1 *)
        FI;
    ELSE
        (* PE = 1, interrupt or trap gate, DPL >= CPL *)
        IF VM = 1
            #GP(error_code(new code-segment selector, 0, EXT)); (* idt operand to error_code is 0 because selector is used *)
        FI;
        IF new code segment is conforming or new code-segment DPL = CPL
            GOTO INTRA-PRIVILEGE-LEVEL-INTERRUPT;
        ELSE
            (* PE = 1, interrupt or trap gate, nonconforming code segment, DPL > CPL *)
            #GP(error_code(new code-segment selector, 0, EXT)); (* idt operand to error_code is 0 because selector is used *)
        FI;
    FI;
END;
INTER-PRIVILEGE-LEVEL-INTERRUPT: (* PE = 1, interrupt or trap gate, non-conforming code segment, DPL < CPL *)
    IF (IA32_EFER.LMA = 0) (* Not IA-32e mode *)
        (* Identify stack-segment selector for new privilege level in current TSS *)
        IF current TSS is 32-bit
            TSSstackAddress = (new code-segment DPL << 3) + 4;
            IF (TSSstackAddress + 5) > current TSS limit
                #TS(error_code(current TSS selector, 0, EXT));
            FI;
            (* idt operand to error_code is 0 because selector is used *)
            NewSS = 2 bytes loaded from (TSS base + TSSstackAddress + 4);
            NewESP = 4 bytes loaded from (TSS base + TSSstackAddress);
        ELSE
            (* current TSS is 16-bit *)
            TSSstackAddress = (new code-segment DPL << 2) + 2
            IF (TSSstackAddress + 3) > current TSS limit
                #TS(error_code(current TSS selector, 0, EXT));
            FI;
            (* idt operand to error_code is 0 because selector is used *)
            NewSS = 2 bytes loaded from (TSS base + TSSstackAddress + 2);
            NewESP = 2 bytes loaded from (TSS base + TSSstackAddress);
        FI;
        IF NewSS is NULL
            #TS(EXT);
        FI;
        IF NewSS index is not within its descriptor-table limits or NewSS RPL != new code-segment DPL
            #TS(error_code(NewSS, 0, EXT));
        FI;
        (* idt operand to error_code is 0 because selector is used *)
        Read new stack-segment descriptor for NewSS in GDT or LDT;
        IF new stack-segment DPL != new code-segment DPL or new stack-segment Type does not indicate writable data segment
            #TS(error_code(NewSS, 0, EXT));
        FI;
        (* idt operand to error_code is 0 because selector is used *)
        IF NewSS is not present
            #SS(error_code(NewSS, 0, EXT));
        FI; (* idt operand to error_code is 0 because selector is used *)
    ELSE
        (* IA-32e mode *)
        IF IDT-gate IST = 0
            TSSstackAddress = (new code-segment DPL << 3) + 4;
        ELSE
            TSSstackAddress = (IDT gate IST << 3) + 28;
        FI;
        IF (TSSstackAddress + 7) > current TSS limit
            #TS(error_code(current TSS selector, 0, EXT);
        FI;
        (* idt operand to error_code is 0 because selector is used *)
        NewRSP = 8 bytes loaded from (current TSS base + TSSstackAddress);
        NewSS = new code-segment DPL; (* NULL selector with RPL = new CPL *)
    FI;
    IF IDT gate is 32-bit
        IF new stack does not have room for 24 bytes (error code pushed) or 20 bytes (no error code pushed)
            #SS(error_code(NewSS, 0, EXT));
            (* idt operand to error_code is 0 because selector is used *)
        FI
    ELSE
        IF IDT gate is 16-bit
            IF new stack does not have room for 12 bytes (error code pushed) or 10 bytes (no error code pushed);
                #SS(error_code(NewSS, 0, EXT));
            FI; (* idt operand to error_code is 0 because selector is used *)
        ELSE
            (* 64-bit IDT gate *)
            IF StackAddress is non-canonical
                #SS(EXT);
            FI; (* Error code contains NULL selector *)
        FI;
    FI;
    IF (IA32_EFER.LMA = 0) (* Not IA-32e mode *)
        IF instruction pointer from IDT gate is not within new code-segment limits
            #GP(EXT);
        FI; (* Error code contains NULL selector *)
        ESP = NewESP;
        SS = NewSS; (* Segment descriptor information also loaded *)
    ELSE
        (* IA-32e mode *)
        IF instruction pointer from IDT gate contains a non-canonical address
            #GP(EXT);
        FI; (* Error code contains NULL selector *)
        RSP = NewRSP & FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0H;
        SS = NewSS;
    FI;
    IF IDT gate is 32-bit
        CS:EIP = Gate(CS:EIP); (* Segment descriptor information also loaded *)
    ELSE
        IF IDT gate 16-bit
            CS:IP = Gate(CS:IP); (* Segment descriptor information also loaded *)
        ELSE
            (* 64-bit IDT gate *)
            CS:RIP = Gate(CS:RIP); (* Segment descriptor information also loaded *)
        FI;
    FI;
    IF IDT gate is 32-bit
        Push(far pointer to old stack); (* Old SS and ESP, 3 words padded to 4 *)
        Push(EFLAGS);
        Push(far pointer to return instruction); (* Old CS and EIP, 3 words padded to 4 *)
        Push(ErrorCode); (* If needed, 4 bytes *)
    ELSE
        IF IDT gate 16-bit
            Push(far pointer to old stack); (* Old SS and SP, 2 words *)
            Push(EFLAGS(15-0]);
            Push(far pointer to return instruction); (* Old CS and IP, 2 words *)
            Push(ErrorCode); (* If needed, 2 bytes *)
        ELSE
            (* 64-bit IDT gate *)
            Push(far pointer to old stack); (* Old SS and SP, each an 8-byte push *)
            Push(RFLAGS); (* 8-byte push *)
            Push(far pointer to return instruction); (* Old CS and RIP, each an 8-byte push *)
            Push(ErrorCode); (* If needed, 8-bytes *)
        FI;
    FI;
    CPL = new code-segment DPL;
    CS(RPL) = CPL;
    IF IDT gate is interrupt gate
        IF = 0 (* Interrupt flag set to 0, interrupts disabled *);
    FI;
    TF = 0;
    VM = 0;
    RF = 0;
    NT = 0;
END;
INTERRUPT-FROM-VIRTUAL-8086-MODE: (* Identify stack-segment selector for privilege level 0 in current TSS *)
    IF current TSS is 32-bit
        IF TSS limit < 9
            #TS(error_code(current TSS selector, 0, EXT));
        FI;
        (* idt operand to error_code is 0 because selector is used *)
        NewSS = 2 bytes loaded from (current TSS base + 8);
        NewESP = 4 bytes loaded from (current TSS base + 4);
    ELSE
        (* current TSS is 16-bit *)
        IF TSS limit < 5
            #TS(error_code(current TSS selector, 0, EXT));
        FI; (* idt operand to error_code is 0 because selector is used *)
        NewSS = 2 bytes loaded from (current TSS base + 4);
        NewESP = 2 bytes loaded from (current TSS base + 2);
    FI;
    IF NewSS is NULL
        #TS(EXT);
    FI; (* Error code contains NULL selector *)
    IF NewSS index is not within its descriptor table limits or NewSS RPL != 0
        #TS(error_code(NewSS, 0, EXT));
    FI;
    (* idt operand to error_code is 0 because selector is used *)
    Read new stack-segment descriptor for NewSS in GDT or LDT;
    IF new stack-segment DPL != 0 or stack segment does not indicate writable data segment
        #TS(error_code(NewSS, 0, EXT));
    FI;
    (* idt operand to error_code is 0 because selector is used *)
    IF new stack segment not present
        #SS(error_code(NewSS, 0, EXT));
    FI; (* idt operand to error_code is 0 because selector is used *)
    IF IDT gate is 32-bit
        IF new stack does not have room for 40 bytes (error code pushed) or 36 bytes (no error code pushed)
            #SS(error_code(NewSS, 0, EXT));
        FI;
        (* idt operand to error_code is 0 because selector is used *)
    ELSE
        (* IDT gate is 16-bit *)
        IF new stack does not have room for 20 bytes (error code pushed) or 18 bytes (no error code pushed)
            #SS(error_code(NewSS, 0, EXT));
        FI;
        (* idt operand to error_code is 0 because selector is used *)
    FI;
    IF instruction pointer from IDT gate is not within new code-segment limits
        #GP(EXT);
    FI; (* Error code contains NULL selector *)
    tempEFLAGS = EFLAGS;
    VM = 0;
    TF = 0;
    RF = 0;
    NT = 0;
    IF service through interrupt gate
        IF = 0;
    FI;
    TempSS = SS;
    TempESP = ESP;
    SS = NewSS;
    ESP = NewESP;
    (* Following pushes are 16 bits for 16-bit IDT gates and 32 bits for 32-bit IDT gates;Segment selector pushes in 32-bit mode are padded to two words *)
    Push(GS);
    Push(FS);
    Push(DS);
    Push(ES);
    Push(TempSS);
    Push(TempESP);
    Push(TempEFlags);
    Push(CS);
    Push(EIP);
    GS = 0; (* Segment registers made NULL, invalid for use in protected mode *)
    FS = 0;
    DS = 0;
    ES = 0;
    CS:IP = Gate(CS); (* Segment descriptor information also loaded *)
    IF OperandSize = 32
        EIP = Gate(instruction pointer);
    ELSE
        (* OperandSize is 16 *)
        EIP = Gate(instruction pointer) AND 0000FFFFH;
    FI;
    (* Start execution of new routine in Protected Mode *)
END;
INTRA-PRIVILEGE-LEVEL-INTERRUPT:
    (* PE = 1, DPL = CPL or conforming segment *)
    IF IA32_EFER.LMA = 1 (* IA-32e mode *)
        IF IDT-descriptor IST != 0
            TSSstackAddress = (IDT-descriptor IST << 3) + 28;
            IF (TSSstackAddress + 7) > TSS limit
                #TS(error_code(current TSS selector, 0, EXT));
            FI;
            (* idt operand to error_code is 0 because selector is used *)
            NewRSP = 8 bytes loaded from (current TSS base + TSSstackAddress);
        FI;
        IF 32-bit gate (* implies IA32_EFER.LMA = 0 *)
            IF current stack does not have room for 16 bytes (error code pushed) or 12 bytes (no error code pushed)
                #SS(EXT);
            FI; (* Error code contains NULL selector *)
        ELSE
            IF 16-bit gate (* implies IA32_EFER.LMA = 0 *)
                IF current stack does not have room for 8 bytes (error code pushed) or 6 bytes (no error code pushed)
                    #SS(EXT);
                FI; (* Error code contains NULL selector *)
            ELSE
                (* IA32_EFER.LMA = 1, 64-bit gate *)
                IF NewRSP contains a non-canonical address
                    #SS(EXT); (* Error code contains NULL selector *)
                FI;
            FI;
        FI;
    FI;
    IF (IA32_EFER.LMA = 0) (* Not IA-32e mode *)
        IF instruction pointer from IDT gate is not within new code-segment limit
            #GP(EXT);
        FI; (* Error code contains NULL selector *)
    ELSE
        IF instruction pointer from IDT gate contains a non-canonical address
            #GP(EXT);
        FI; (* Error code contains NULL selector *)
        RSP = NewRSP & FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0H;
    FI;
    IF IDT gate is 32-bit (* implies IA32_EFER.LMA = 0 *)
        Push (EFLAGS);
        Push (far pointer to return instruction); (* 3 words padded to 4 *)
        CS:EIP = Gate(CS:EIP); (* Segment descriptor information also loaded *)
        Push (ErrorCode); (* If any *)
    ELSE
        IF IDT gate is 16-bit (* implies IA32_EFER.LMA = 0 *)
            Push (FLAGS);
            Push (far pointer to return location); (* 2 words *)
            CS:IP = Gate(CS:IP); (* Segment descriptor information also loaded *)
            Push (ErrorCode); (* If any *)
        ELSE
            (* IA32_EFER.LMA = 1, 64-bit gate *)
            Push(far pointer to old stack); (* Old SS and SP, each an 8-byte push *)
            Push(RFLAGS); (* 8-byte push *)
            Push(far pointer to return instruction); (* Old CS and RIP, each an 8-byte push *)
            Push(ErrorCode); (* If needed, 8 bytes *)
            CS:RIP = GATE(CS:RIP);
            (* Segment descriptor information also loaded *)
        FI;
    FI;
    CS(RPL) = CPL;
    IF IDT gate is interrupt gate
        IF = 0;
    FI;
    (* Interrupt flag set to 0;interrupts disabled *)
    TF = 0;
    NT = 0;
    VM = 0;
    RF = 0;
END;
```

Comment: Why is it that SS consumes 4 bytes? I understand segment selectors consume 2 bytes. What am I missing?

Comment: @gztomas The alignment. The 2 additional bytes are fillers, so that the stack stays aligned at a multiple of 4.

Comment: `SS` / `ESP` get saved to the stack if/when a stack switch occurs; while this is default for inter-privilege events (interrupt while in usermode / ring 3) and non-default for intra-privilege events (interrupt while already in kernel / ring 0) you can _force_ it to occur even intra-privilege by putting a _task gate_ in the IDT. This is not particularly common (the example I know is Solaris 32bit/x86 for double faults, `#DF` because it's a reasonable way to assure a "good stack to start with", while being able to retain all register state including the value of the "bad stackpointer"), though.